# TzScan API for alphanet?

Tags: transactions, tzscan, alphanet

Does the [TzScan API](https://alphanet.tzscan.io/api) support alphanet operations?

For example, [this query in mainnet](https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/operation/oogKXTkRmJLBmnBQgP2My4QKRHAGLez96krSFshhg51hA8GEMVp) works. But [this query for alphanet](https://api6.tzscan.io/v3/operation/ooTC8mMZ7dG1ReCXLPiTAN3qEUB7uNFuh9R8KZXEFbZZiZcypBf) does not work even though the ophash `ooTC8mMZ7dG1ReCXLPiTAN3qEUB7uNFuh9R8KZXEFbZZiZcypBf` [is valid in alphanet](https://alphanet.tzscan.io/ooTC8mMZ7dG1ReCXLPiTAN3qEUB7uNFuh9R8KZXEFbZZiZcypBf).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After inspecting TzScan's alphanet frontend, i've been able to extract the following curl request:

```
curl 'https://api.alphanet.tzscan.io/v1/operation/ooZXgbKsbHDwMof1mfRxgWXDsjGVZ4FMbwoJdVDyB3nzEAJVsBh' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: https://alphanet.tzscan.io' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: https://alphanet.tzscan.io/ooZXgbKsbHDwMof1mfRxgWXDsjGVZ4FMbwoJdVDyB3nzEAJVsBh' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --compressed
```

Of course you can try `/v3/operation` as well, and it will work, even with your op hash, try the following:

```
curl 'https://api.alphanet.tzscan.io/v1/operation/ooTC8mMZ7dG1ReCXLPiTAN3qEUB7uNFuh9R8KZXEFbZZiZcypBf' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: https://alphanet.tzscan.io' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: https://alphanet.tzscan.io/ooZXgbKsbHDwMof1mfRxgWXDsjGVZ4FMbwoJdVDyB3nzEAJVsBh' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --compressed
```

I'm not sure where `api6.tzscan.io` is pointing at, but `api.alphanet.tzscan.io` seems to work with alphanet. Alternatively you can run TzScan locally with your Alphanet node, if you wan't to fully in control.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried https://api.alphanet.tzscan.io/v3/operation/ooTC8mMZ7dG1ReCXLPiTAN3qEUB7uNFuh9R8KZXEFbZZiZcypBf and it worked!