# Why is my delegation+origination appearing in red?

Tags: baking, delegating, tzscan, contract, account

I used SimpleStaking wallet to delegate 2599 tezos to TezosBC baker but it doesn't seem to be going through. I tried opening with TezBox wallet and it says the account is not on the blockchain yet when its been more than a few hours, how can I fix this?

https://tzscan.io/BKvEMwZRNqEJvBCCZfQ96dggtWM2Zf8wjc9h17PtDF3YVS9trf7?default=origination&p_end=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation failed because you didn't have enough funds to pay the origination burn. You have to do a new origination. But keep 0.3 tez on your implicit account (tz) this time, so you have enough to cover for the burn fee (0.257).

To the more general question why an operation failed, an answer is available here:
[How can I understand why a transaction has failed?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/172/how-can-i-understand-why-a-transaction-has-failed/177#177)

Comment: I've done as you said, this time it says my delegate is tezosBC https://tzscan.io/KT1K1xG1onxwrRLyrKoxTLoLRiSmQAgBmBTW
Does that mean I am part of the baking process via a delegate now? Will I get rewards for my stake after some time?

Comment: From a technical viewpoint you have now delegated successfully. But I see now that TezosBC is over-delegated. You should contact them to make sure if they accept your delegation. Bakers can have different policies when it comes to over-delegations.

Comment: It would appear that tezosbc has added more funds for the bond amount, does that mean all is good?

https://mytezosbaker.com/tezosbc

Comment: It should be good in that case. Some bakers keep tez that is not needed in the bond on a separate address for security reasons. Then when it's needed they can just transfer more funds to the baker address.